# move www directory to home?

Tags: permissions, apache2, 18.04

I create /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/USER/www/public_html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Then I do:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default && sudo a2ensite mysite
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Now if I do grep -R "DocumentRoot" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled it respond with:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf: DocumentRoot /home/USER/www/public_html
```

If I do ls -l in /home/USER/ it respond with:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 USER USER   4096 giu 10 20:23  www
```

If I do ls -l in /home/USER/www it respond with:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 USER USER 4096 giu 16 12:05 public_html
```

But if I go to http://localhost/ it respond with:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
-----------------------------------------------------
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Why?

Comment: If you have created the directory on /home/USER/www manually, I think you need to change the permissions to chmod 755.

Comment: Just use userdir https://www.google.com/amp/s/websiteforstudents.com/setup-apache2-userdir-module-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-servers/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache requires permissions to all the directories all the way up to the root of the file system where the site is hosted.

- `/home` is not owned by your user but by root.
- changing /home permissions from root:root to USER:USER will break your system.

So no: It is NOT a good idea to set /home/USER/www/ for apache. Please use the default /var/www/. **All you need is a SYMLINK from `/var/www/` to `/home/USER/wwww/`.**

Your .conf is missing parts. I am missing the `<Directory "/directory/documentroot">` tag and the `Require all granted`.

Comment: Does not it also require to set that location inside de `apache.conf`/`httpd.conf` file?

Comment: I solve!
I add in  /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf the followind line:
  <Directory /home/USER/www/public_html>
                AllowOverride All
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                Require all granted
        </Directory>